# Как добавить AAAA запись для dns? Что означают цифры перед :: в ipv6?

Tags: centos, ip, dns

Certbot нужно добавить AAAA record для генерации ssl. Я проверил ip6 с помощью команды `ip -6 addr`. Получил запись формата

```
ХХХХ::ХХХХ:ХХХХ:ХХХХ:ХХХХ/64
```

При этом у провайдера dns формат ввода:

```
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Как добавить мой ip в AAAA запись? Важны ли цифры перед `::` или их можно проигнорировать?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/444554/what-does-mean-as-an-ip-address-bracket-colon-colon-bracket

Comment: Грубо говоря, '::' - замена нулевых блоков в IPv6 адресе. По-поводу добавления AAAA записи в домен, необходимо проверить документации или рекомендации вашего регистратора

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0